# JMETER 4. 0 | JMeter distributed load testing | jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group | Report

Tags: performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0, distributed-testing

How to extract a report for the testing consisting of the below model on the distributed testing environment.

- Master(My own machine)
- 2 slaves machines
- Thread: jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group

Basically wanted to have a dashboard report.

Comment: Have you checked [this manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a dashboard report by [running your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) from the **master** node like:

```
jmeter -n -R slave1,slave2 -t /path/to/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/result.csv -e -o /path/to/dashboard/folder
```

Once test finishes you can open `/path/to/dashboard/folder/index.html` file with your favourite web browser and see the metrics and charts.

References:

- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)
- [Remote Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [HTML Reporting Dashboard: Generating Reports](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report)

---

Please be informed that according to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so I would recommend switching to [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) (or whatever is the latest version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) as soon as possible